# Sample code to download data from a real website api

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I am trying to create code to download the data into a CSV from an actual website. I have not coded in languages other than SQL/PL-SQL/T-SQL for more than 10 years.

I am familiar with Python, Java and C++.

If someone could post sample working code that connects to an actual website and downloads its data into a CSV (or even JSON) I could learn from it and clone for the website api from which I need to pull the data from.

I did some googling and found some leads, but still confused and lost where to start.

Please help :)

Comment: "I did some googling and found some leads, but still confused and lost where to start." Then please ask a specific question. Questions like "give me the code" are not well suited for Stackoverflow. Especially as there are thousands of examples already on the Internet.

Comment: see https://github.com/fujiaoliu/rezina#example-cityweather, there is a example to download weather data from yahoo weather api.

Comment: Try reading the [beautiful soup documentation](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/) and learnt from it.